# My outlets are not being referenced

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Though I ctrl + drag, it gets referenced....but when I run the app it crashes with NSException... when I check on it says my view controller does not have an outlet named gif view and also the action check_internet is not defined on the view controller. The following is my view controller code.

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController{
func checkreachability()
{
    if currentReachabilityStatus == .notReachable
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet ", message: "Please Check Your Internet Connection", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var gifview: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gifview.loadGif(name: "source")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @IBAction func check_internet(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    checkreachability()
  }

}
```

Comment: check your outlets are connected properly & remove old outlets.

Comment: @nithinsampath You sure the `viewController` class is given in the class field in storyBoard? Also make sure there are no multiple classes named 'ViewController'

Comment: i am sorry...since i am a noob...can you please elaborate @DSDharma

Comment: Yes i am absolutely sure  ...@Bali

Comment: Did it happened after updating XCode?

Comment: Nope...initially it was working....when i continued to build more pages....suddenly this error popped up from nowhere....@Bali

Comment: Try removing the reference to the `ViewController.swift`. Then re-add it to the project, clean and build again.

Comment: @nithinsampath Did you checked that?

Comment: thanks a lot....it worked perfectly now....thank you @Bali

Comment: @nithinsampath I will add it as answer. plz accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the reference to the `ViewController.swift`. Then re-add it to the project, clean and build again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create weak reference.
as weak references can not hold 
Remove weak from your `@IBOutlet` and try again

Comment: You are working on image. but you reference is weak property so it can not hold data. that is why you are getting crash